# Embeding video in Safari

Tags: http, macos, browser, video, safari

Below is the source code for my html web page on Safari.
But when I am opening this web page it displays the source code instead of playing the video.

Any help on this will be appreciated.
I am completely new to this domain so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: <video width="640" height="360" poster="poster.jpg" controls autoplay>
<source src="Screen_4.mov";type="video/mp4">
</source>
</video>

Comment: Please reward the people who have helped you in the past and accept some answers. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Displays the source code?  Are you certain it isn't actually dropping '&lt;' / '&gt;' into your code?  As an element, even if it isn't understood by the browser (which shouldn't be the case here), it shouldn't show the source.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your response. So what could be wrong here. Is there some settings on the server which I am missing.

Comment: Most likely, the issue is in the source of the file containing the video tag.  

Generally, the web server doesn't care what is in the file... unless your server is sending the wrong MIME type.  If your files generally look like HTML, this is unlikely.